# Running tor on 2 ISPs with load balancing

Tags: relays, bridge, load-balance

I have 2 ISPs (Vivo and NET) on load balancing by my Cisco RV340. This makes outside internet peers to see me as if I kept alternating 2 different IPs, because each connection is randomly sent to one of them.

I bought a small PC a week ago and installed Ubuntu on it and now installed a Tor bridge relay. Its log is showing messages like `Your network connection speed appears to have changed. Resetting timeout to 60s after 18 timeouts`, `Our IP Address has changed from XXXXXXX to YYYYYYY; rebuilding descriptor`.

To make it worse, NET ISP has port forwarding blocked. DMZ and manual forwarding was tried on its modem and it was in vain, I'm believing they are blocking inbound connections from outside their modem. Vivo is working fine, including DMZ.

My server is connected to router as a simple cable, and ALAIK this load balancing is transparent to my PCs, I can't setup them to use only 1 specific ISP. I also looked around RV340 admin for something that could help and found nothing.

Any idea what I could do to make my relay work healthy?

Answer (score 1):

This question might be best asked of the [tor-relay mailing list](https://lists.torproject.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/tor-relays/) because there is a better chance that a developer will see it. However, it seems to me that a relay should only see a single stable IP connection. If the relay sees two IP's then it might freak out like you are seeing. It might be better if the Tor relay saw a single internal IP behind a loadbalancer than for it to see two external real IPs. Can you confirm if the relay is using one or both of the external IP addresses or just one internal IP?

Also, I checked the Tor [bug history and wiki](https://trac.torproject.org/) for situations like yours and it looks like either no one has tried it or at least hasn't been reported.

Comment: What I've noticed is that when it's using Vivo IP it confirms it's reached from outside, and when it's using NET IP it says it's uncreachable. As long as I'm unable to redirect ports on NET modem, this IP will pretty much be dead for use as any server.